# Replicate Move to trash in firestore for file management system

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore to replicate the file manager like google drive in which i have 2 collections Folders and Files , with the following structure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz6R9.png):
In Folders collection there are multiple folders document and each document contains files(array of child files ) folders(array of child folders) parent(id of parent folder) and path(complete heirachy till now using id of folders) and name of the folder( i have main , shared folders, trash as the root folders)

and the Files collection contains document of files where each file contains the name and the parent folder id

Now i want to replicate the move to trash functionality , for which i am thinking to add new field in folder document oldpath(in which i copy the path) and update path by trash document id , in this way i will be able to replicate like that folder moved to trash but i am not sure what should i do with the child folders and files
Also i can access each folder from the front end with the url "/folders/{folderId}" so if i do the above mentioned approach to update the path then that folder i'll see in the shared document but if i access its child element by the url then it will be visible to user which i dont want , i want that if user go to that url they are sent back to trash folder url

Comment: A lot depends on your needs, but did you consider giving each file/folder document a flag to indicate whether it's deleted or not? That way you can query for files/folders `where('deleted', '==', false)` (or `true` if needed). It'll keep things much simpler, and is how some common file systems perform deletions under the hood.

Comment: Did you try Frank's recommendation?

Comment: I followed a slightly different approach , i removed the child link from parents folder and add the reference of that folder to deleted folder collection , so now using the path i can check if folder is deleted (if any of the id in path is in the deleted folder document it means its deleted)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.